# "A()" vs. "A() = default;" vs. Implicit A()?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

```
#include <vector>

// version 1
struct A
{
    std::vector<int> m_coll;

    // The compiler will generate a ctor A() here
};

// version 2
struct A
{
    std::vector<int> m_coll;
    A(){}
};

// version 3
struct A
{
    std::vector<int> m_coll;
    A() : m_coll(){}
};

// version 4
struct A
{
    std::vector<int> m_coll;
    A() = default;
};
```

What are the differences between the four versions?

Is `m_coll` guaranteed to be default-initialized in all of these versions?

Comment: Look up what each one does and compare.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit to be honest it is easy to miss that `= default` and relying on implicit declaration works differently in presence of other constructors.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: Easy to miss, yes; but you have to do some research first in order to have any chance at all.

Comment: I can't think of any scenario where a data member would *not* get default initialized, unless explicitly initialized to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to consider the various options whenever you add an extra datum.  Consider:

```
struct A {
  int i;
  std::vector<int> coll;
};
```

In this case, the compiler generates the default c'tor for you, but `i` is uninitialized, so you'll have to set it explicitly.

Let's improve things:

```
struct B {
  int i {};
  std::vector<int> coll;
};
```

For `B`, the compiler also generates a default c'tor for you, but `i` is initialized in-class, and so a default-constructed object of type `B` is fully initialized.  Now suppose I want to add a user-defined c'tor:

```
struct C {
  int i {};
  std::vector<int> coll;
  C(int const j) : i{j} {}
};
```

Adding the user-defined c'tor suppresses the automatic generation of a default constructor.  So to enable a default c'tor, one can do a few different things:

```
struct D1 {
  int i {};
  std::vector<int> coll;
  D1(int const j) : i{j} {}
  D1(){}
};
```

Although the above is well-formed, I find it ugly.  Here `D1(){}` *is* the default c'tor, and `i` is appropriately initialized since it has an in-class initializer.  However, it is more descriptive to do something like:

```
struct D2 {
  int i {};
  std::vector<int> coll;
  D2(int const j) : i{j} {}
  D2() = default;
};
```

This way, you can *read* that you are enabling a default c'tor.

In my experience, it is more helpful to use `default` whenever one needs to enable a default definition for copy/move constructors and assignment operators and a default definition for virtual destructors.

**Long story short:** Use `default` whenever you need to enable a c'tor or assignment operator that the compiler would otherwise suppress, or when you need a default definition for a virtual destructor.